# Unity video Ads stuck, DEBUG [T:0x74262000 M] -[UnityAdsVideoViewController videoPlaybackStalled]:334

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, video-ads

I am trying to integrate UnityVideo ads into my iOS game made in SpriteKit  and It appears the integration is successful, I followed http://unityads.unity3d.com/help/Documentation%20for%20Publishers/Integration-Guide-for-iOS

Now when i try to play test ads On my device the video ad plays for 1-2 seconds and then gets stuck forever in "buffering" state

[image]

Following gets printed in the console continuously......

DEBUG [T:0x74262000 M] -[UnityAdsVideoPlayer _videoProgressMonitor:]:257 VIDEO MOVED: 0.000000

DEBUG [T:0x74262000 M] -[UnityAdsVideoPlayer _videoProgressMonitor:]:259 VIDEO STALLED!

DEBUG [T:0x74262000 M] -[UnityAdsVideoViewController videoPlaybackStalled]:334

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this response from Unity, via email. It may help you:

> Usually the VIDEO STALLED message is caused by poor network connectivity. What this means is that your app does not have enough time after initializing the Unity Ads -system to cache ads and it tries to fall back to streaming mode.
>
> There are a couple ways to solve this:
>
> 1. You could allow more time to pass inside your app after initializing the ads before calling the first ad.
> 2. We could disable ad streaming for your game. What this means is that it'll force the devices to cache the ads first. This of course means that it takes a little longer for the ads to become available.